# Android video still playing after exiting app

Tags: android, video, webview

If exit my android app and a video is still playing (delivered via WebView), you can still hear it in the background. 
How to resolve this issue?  I don't really want to try to Force close the application; is there a way to pause everything coming from the WebView activity untill the user returns to the app?

Edit:

I tried

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.onPause(); 
}
```

but app crashes when exiting

Comment: android lifecycle : `onPause` stop it

Comment: @Blundell how to stop WebView though within the onPause?  I can't find a command for that..

Answer (score 1):

You have to call super.onPause() when you override Activity's onPuase:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mWebView.onPause();
    super.onPause();  // Don't forget this line
}
```

Otherwise you will get this error:
**android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity did not call through to super.onPause()**

Comment: Don't forget webView.onResume() also

Answer (score 0):

try this : `mWebView.playSoundEffect(0);` or `mWebView.clearCache(true);`